# JQuery appending a drop down option reducing whitespace into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I am trying to dynamically append a option in select list using jQuery:

```js
let text1 = "jg";
console.log("length of text: " + text1.length);
$("#selectList").append($('<option>', {
    value: 12,
    text: text1
}));
```

This time it gives length of text: 7

Now I want to retrieve the selected text from select list but when I do that I get the text which has only one white space in the middle rest of the white space in between is truncated. The code I used to retrieve value from select list pasted below:

```js
let e = document.getElementById("selectList");
let selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
console.log("text: " + selected);
console.log("selected length: " + selected.length);
```

Now the text is just `j`, `g`, and `selected length: 3`. How can I get the above 7 length long text from select list?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `innerHTML` instead of `text`:

```js
let text1 = 'j     g';
console.log("length of text: " + text1.length);
$("#selectList").append($('<option>', {
    value: 12,
    text: text1
}));

let e = document.getElementById("selectList");
let selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
console.log("text: " + selected);
console.log("selected length: " + selected.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='selectList' ></select>
```

You can even use `innerText` instead of `text`:

```js
let text1 = 'j     g';
console.log("length of text: " + text1.length);
$("#selectList").append($('<option>', {
    value: 12,
    text: text1
}));

let e = document.getElementById("selectList");
let selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerText;
console.log("text: " + selected);
console.log("selected length: " + selected.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='selectList'></select>
```

Comment: You *can* use `.innerHTML`, but since there is no HTML to parse, it's a bit of a waste. Use, `.textContent` instead.

Comment: Either of them can be used `innerText` or `innerHTML`. And not necessarily `textContent`

Comment: Yes, I said that, but `.innerHTML` is going to parse the text for any HTML. Since there isn't any, it's wasteful and in those cases, `.textContent` should be used.

Comment: Then why did you changed your answer from `textContent` to JQuery `text()`. You should stick with your answer if you were confident with it.

Comment: Read my reply to your comment below. You should *read* before you type.

Comment: You added snippet with `textContent` and now you changed that with `JQuery`. You get that what I am saying?

Comment: Also @ScottMarcus making a comment does not mean you down vote my answer. Have a sportsman spirit.

Comment: Yes, and what's the problem with that. Look at the OPs code - he's using JQuery. I still have the same information about `.textContent` in my answer.

Comment: Oh, like you didn't down vote me. I don't know who you are mad at, but you need to chill. I simply made a valid comment about your answer and you flipped out.

Comment: why should I down vote yours. Check the votes, both are 0 in upvote and downvote. Also, I haven't said your answer is incorrect. So, why should I down vote it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.textContent` DOM property of the `select` and you will avoid the whitespace normalization that naturally occurs when text is parsed as HTML.

But, since you are using JQuery, it doesn't make sense to mix and match vanilla DOM APIs when you're already using jQuery.

With jQuery, you can use the `.text()` method of element to get the same result.

```js
let text1 = "j     g";
console.log("length of text: " + text1.length);

let $list = $("#selectList");
$list.append($('<option>', {
  value: 12,
  text: text1
}));

console.log("text: " + $list.text());
console.log("selected length: " + $list.text().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectList"></select>
```

Comment: Why don't you stick with a same answer. Think twice before you answer.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal What?! I still have the original answer. I just added more to it to make it more complete since the OP is using JQuery. Think twice before you make comments that make no sense.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Stack Overflow contributors are allowed - and _encouraged_ - to edit their questions and answers to improve them. For example, I often post a short answer to help someone get going right away, and then I may revise the answer a few times to add more information, perhaps some background and documentation links, and for general readability and clarity. This is a good thing to do, not a bad thing. The quick answer gives immediate help, and then the extra editing makes the answer more useful to future visitors.